# AddVersionedApiExplorer not working in Asp.Versioning?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnet-api-versioning

I am learning ASP.NET Core and encounter with the following compiler error CS1061 on `AddVersionedApiExplorer`:

[image].

I am using the following at the beginning of my code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Asp.Versioning;
using Asp.Versioning.ApiExplorer;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
```

I have also installed

```
Asp.Versioning.Mvc
Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer,
```

However, I still can't solve the error.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/1096), the usage of the  ApiExplorer is like below:

```
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning( ).AddApiExplorer(options => { 

    options.GroupNameFormat = "json";
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});
```

Comment: Hi Brando, the error is solved. Thank you so much for the help!  Phil

Comment: Hi, done. My first time here. :)